# What is the relation between Mojang and Oxeye games?

Tags: cobalt

Since the game Cobalt requires a Mojang account, but the Oxeye games site claims they are independent?

```
We are Oxeye Game Studio, a small independent Swedish game developer.
```

Comment: Also, playcobalt.com is down with a SOPA protest notice signed "Sincerely, Mojang".

Comment: Notch hired the developers of Oxeye to work at Mojang. They were already working on their own game - Cobalt - which was then published by Mojang.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mojang is the publisher for Oxeye's *Cobalt*. It is Mojang's first third-party game.

Source: [Joystiq](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/08/18/mojang-unveils-first-third-party-game-cobalt/)

Comment: Should also be noted that Jeb appears to work on both Mojang and Oxeye projects.